# How do I submit a form with modal start button?

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

With PHP, I tried to use bootstrap modal to preview form posts.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Dashboard</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <?php include('config/css.php'); ?> <!-- including bootstrap css cdn links -->
    <?php include('config/js.php'); ?>   <!-- including jquery cdn links -->     
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<table width="75%" align="center" class="table">
  <tbody>    
<tr>
  <td width="10%" align="left"><label>Item Name</label></td>          

  <td width="35%">
      <form method="POST" name="submit">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemname" id="itemname" placeholder="Type Item Name"></form>
  </td>      

  <td width="10%" align="left"><label>Item Description</label></td>          

  <td width="35%">
      <form method="POST" name="submit">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemdes" id="itemdes" placeholder="Type Item Description"></form>
  </td> 

</tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input data-toggle="modal" data-target=".previewModal" class="btn btn-success" value="Create Preview"> <!-- Modal Start Button -->

<div class="modal fade previewModal">  <!-- Starting Modal -->
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

<div class="modal-content">        
    <div class="modal-header">Item Name Will be Here</div>       
    <div class="modal-body">Item Description Will be Here</div>             
    <div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div>
</div>

</div>
</div> <!-- End Modal -->

</body>
</html>
```

Right now it has only a button that pops up modal window. How can I submit the form elements inside the preview modal without another button?

Comment: Without another button? Do  you want the user to interact with the modal using mental prestidigitation?

Comment: Put your form into <div class="modal-content">  block
Be careful,you have a 2 opened form

Comment: i think my modal popup start button can submit forms in same time maybe, i've try that but this way isnt working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button").click(function(){
    $("form").submit(); 
    });

});
```

Comment: i renamed my modal start name="button" and id="button"
also renamed form name="fom" and id="form"
added that script code inside <script> </script> bracelets but working yet
I guess i need to add a js code in modal start button, onClick="(in here)". is that right?

Comment: you need to add jquery library + try the code in the browser console